# iPad - Text not visible when typing into input field (type="text")

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic2

I have an ionic 2 app with a page, which contains a web form with several input fields.  When I type into the fields, the text is there (i can see the cursor move as I type) but it is not visible until I tap outside of the field or close the virtual keyboard.  I am not using any special styling other than `-webkit-appearance: none;  border-radius: 0;`  Is there something I'm forgetting to set?

Comment: What is the code you are using for the input. I had the same problem with inputs inside of cards

Comment: @gerdi I will try to do a POC in another project.  A bulk of this code was moved from an angular-cli project into an ionic-cli one.  No issues running in ionic serve but as soon as its run on the iOS Sim/Real iPad, I see this invisible text issue on forms with multiple input fields.  <ion-input> code might give some hint as to how the Ionic 2 team handled it.  I will update when I'm able to identify the root cause.

Comment: @gerdi turns out the issue was an implementation bug with a custom checkbox component I was using inside a webform.  I have not found a solution to implement it correctly but I have a feeling it is because I did not implement the ControlValueAccessor interface.  I'll need to spend some time tomorrow to figure it out but at least i narrowed it down.  Commenting out the HTML code that contained the checkbox in it allowed the form to behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Using `-webkit-appearance: none;` is the problem.

Typing in that line makes the input field not visible.